# height of imageview in in listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

good morning i tried to create a custom listview that contains in every item an imageview. 
My pb is that in result the imageview doesn't cover the hole item.
I had a padding in bottom and in the front of the item.
this the xml file for the item row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the xml code of the activity that contains the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <ListView
                 android:id="@+id/listView2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
             </LinearLayout>
```

i hope that someone help me 
this is the item image you see the black padding in the bottom 
[image]

Comment: Please use punctuation, it's really hard to read your question.

Comment: i made some changes i hope it's clear now

Comment: @وليدأبويحيى,still, I can't understand you clearly.

Comment: can you use paint tools to highlight the area of problem in the image attached because it is very hard to understand this question

Comment: Make Imageview's width and height fill parent and set scaleType="fitXY" ,adjustbound to true

Comment: think you very much you help me it work

Comment: remove android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" and as said by Parag Imageview's width and height fill parent and set scaleType="fitXY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use following code in xml .....

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

hope this will work...